# How do I stop "node" asking for my password?

Tags: macos, password, bug, adobe-photoshop

How do I stop "node" asking for my iCloud keychain password (for Adobe Creative Cloud)?

[image]

My goals are

1. never to see this dialog again,
2. to continue using Photoshop.

If I can't accomplish 1 then I'm just going to give up on 2 and find a replacement product (suggestions welcome).

I've tired everything listed in the answers available here from Adobe's support site and here on AD, but none work. Some used to for PS 2020, but no longer for PS 2021 (which is why I suspect this is a new question requiring an updated answer).

Most recently, I contacted Adobe support chat, where I was instructed to use sdfsdf to remove Creative Cloud and was assured that though I (incredibly) would need to reinstall CC in order to update Photoshop, I could at least for the time being still use Photoshop.

But this is not true. After following Adobe support's instructions to remove CC, attempting to launch Photoshop results in:

[image]

In case you think perhaps reinstalling PS might fix that, stop yourself: doing that installs CC as well, and I’m right back where I started from (minus all the lost time).

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so we know not to suggest it?

Comment: @GaussStrife: I've tried everything listed [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=adobe+keeps+asking+me+to+sign+in&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) on the first several 2 or so pages of results. The only thing that works for 1 is to follow the suggestion to remove Creative Cloud entirely, but doing that prevents 2 (PS won't launch any more).

Comment: And: Why are so many unkillable Adobe things running all the time even if I don't launch them myself. And why are they so hard to kill?

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike with windows, managing scheduled tasks, services and startup items is a lot harder. You could use the terminal to do it, but its more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstall Adobe, seriously. The cloud sync and heavy weight tools cost us a full time engineer to wrangle at work. We are locked in, but the alternatives are so much easier to maintain and a delight to use.

Comment: After years postponing the decision, I agree. Looking at Pixelmator and Acorn.

Comment: "Your plan was canceled. Check your email for more details." I feel clean! Now, let's see if I can actually uninstall this hot mess.

Comment: We do love the Adobe uninstall script. I wish we didn’t have to use it so much, but it does clean well on macOS and is well documented online for several versions of their product.

Comment: This is the correct answer: The solution to Adobe issues is simply to get rid of all of their products and [replace them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/426380/4395) with (better, cheaper, and easier to use) alternatives. There's really no reason to use Adobe for anything, unless you are forced to.

Comment: The [inevitable follow up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/426497/4395) is just how to reliably and permanently remove everything.

Comment: Can’t you just run the uninstall for each thing you installed? @orome

Comment: @orome I only have a new version of adobe reader installed, is it benign or should i replace it with something else?  If so, what?